# $\displaystyle\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{1+x+x²}-1}{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

First I need to prove that this limit; $\displaystyle\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{1+x+x^2}-1}{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}$ converges, then I have to find its limit. Now I don't know how to prove that it converges (these epsilon proofs are still something that I'm trying to learn). And to actually find the limit; I tried to rewrite it by multiplying by $\displaystyle{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}\over \sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}$ but I didn't get any further..

Edit: I know that it converges to $1/2$, but that's what wolfram alpha says :|

Comment: Try L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: What methods do you have available (other than algebra)? Can you use L'Hospital's Rule? Did you finish multiplying out the numerator?

Comment: If you also multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt{1+x+x^2}+1$, things will turn out nicely. You will get some harmless stuff times $\frac{x+x^2}{2x}$.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use L'Hospital, we haven't proven L'hospital in our real analysis class. I don't see how multiplying by $\sqrt{1+x+x²}+1$ gives us anything valuable for the bottomside

Comment: Andre wants you to multiply top and bottom by $\big(\sqrt{1+x+x^2}+1\big)\big(\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}\big)$.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I didn't think of that, that's really smart :O

Comment: Don't I need to seperately show that this limit converges first by the way, as this was the original asignment (if so, how? because that troubles me most!)

Comment: If you can evaluate a limit successfully, it automatically shows that the limit exists. You don't need to do "convergence" and "evaluation" separately. I wonder why some textbooks try to frame questions in such a language. In fact in some cases when one is asked to prove convergence, then it is difficult to evaluate the limit in closed form and one has to be content with the convergence part without knowing what value it converges to.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way is to transform the limit into
$$
\lim _{x\to 0}
  \frac{(\sqrt{1+x+x^2}-1)(\sqrt{1+x+x^2}+1)}
       {(\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x})(\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x})}
  \cdot
  \frac{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x+x^2}+1}
$$
that becomes
$$
\lim_{x\to0}
  \frac{x+x^2}{2x}
  \cdot
  \frac{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x+x^2}+1}
=
\lim_{x\to0}
  \frac{1+x}{2}
  \cdot
  \frac{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x+x^2}+1}
$$
The alternative is to use Taylor expansions:
\begin{gather}
\sqrt{1+x+x^2}=1+\frac{1}{2}(x+x^2)+o(x)=1+\frac{1}{2}x+o(x)
\\
\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac{1}{2}x+o(x)
\\
\sqrt{1-x}=1-\frac{1}{2}x+o(x)
\end{gather}
So the limit is
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1+\frac{1}{2}x+o(x)-1}{(1+\frac{1}{2}x+o(x))-(1-\frac{1}{2}x+o(x))}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}x+o(x)}{x+o(x)}=\frac{1}{2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\sqrt{1+x+x^2}-1}{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}=\frac{x+x^2}{(\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x})(\sqrt{1+x+x^2}+1)}=$$   $$=\frac{x+x^2}{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}*\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x+x^2}+1}$$ It follows
$$\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{1+x+x^2}-1}{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}=\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{x+x^2}{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}*\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x+x^2}+1}$$ The second factor is clearly equal to $\color{red}{\frac 12}$ and $$\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{x+x^2}{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}=\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{(x+x^2)(\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x})}{2x}=\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{(1+x)(\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x})}{2}=\frac 22=1$$ Thus the asked limit is equal to $$1\cdot \frac 12=\color{red}{\frac 12}$$